# Placement of Jr. and Sr. with biblatex

Tags: biblatex

In most bibliographic styles, the suffixes `Jr.` and `Sr.` go *after* both names of an author in the bibliography, preceded by a comma:

> Gauch, Hugh G., Jr. (2012). *Scientific method in brief*. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press.

It seems like most `BibTeX` styles have [struggled to get this right](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183228/have-the-bibtex-styles-gotten-the-placement-of-a-names-junior-part-wrong). I've also found now that the default behavior of `biblatex` doesn't follow the standard either. In the example below, the suffix `Jr.` is placed according to the [general guidelines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BibTeX#Author_formatting).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{gauch2012,
    AUTHOR = "Gauch, Jr., Hugh G.",
    TITLE = "Scientific method in brief",
    YEAR = "2012",
    LOCATION = "Cambridge",
    PUBLISHER = "Cambridge University Press"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

I've tried other permutations of the order `First name`, `Last name`, `Jr.` in the `.bib` file, but I haven't found one that gives the desired output.

According to the comments to [Have the BibTeX styles gotten the placement of a name's "junior" part wrong?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183228/have-the-bibtex-styles-gotten-the-placement-of-a-names-junior-part-wrong), both `biblatex-apa` and `biblatex-chicago` have the desired order, so it is at least possible to implement this in `biblatex`. How can I do it?

---

**EDIT**

When implementing Guido's suggestion, the default layout of subsequent authors, which is `first name` - `last name`, changes to `last name` - `comma` -- `first name`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameFormat{author}{%
  \usebibmacro{name:delim}{#5#1}%
  \ifblank{#5}{#1}{#5 #1}\addcomma\addspace
  #3\isdot
  \ifblank{#7}{}{\addcomma\addspace #7}\isdot
}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{gauch2012,
    AUTHOR = "Gauch, Jr., Hugh G.",
    TITLE = "Scientific method in brief",
    YEAR = "2012",
    LOCATION = "Cambridge",
    PUBLISHER = "Cambridge University Press"}
@BOOK{chomsky1968,
    AUTHOR = "Noam Chomsky and Morris Halle",
    TITLE = "The sound pattern of English",
    YEAR = "1968",
    LOCATION = "New York, NY",
    PUBLISHER = "Harper \& Row",
    SERIES = "Studies in language"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I disagree with the claim that "BibTeX has long struggled to get this right". First off, it's not BibTeX itself but the bibliography style that determines *all aspects* of the formatting of an entry, *including* the ordering of the components of authors' names. Second, while the ordering "Last Name, First Name(s), Junior Component" may well be more common than "Last Name, Junior Component, First Name(s)", I don't think it can be said that there's a general rule that favors the first form. Publishers have "house styles" and tastes, and there's no arguing about such styles *or* tastes, right?

Comment: @Mico I've reworded it.

Comment: Thanks. I still think that there's no point in claiming that one style is better than another or that some styles "struggle to get it right". The ordering of the components of authors' names is primarily a matter of style and taste, just as is the issue of whether the names of journals should be set in *italics*, etc. To avoid getting sucked into a pointless debate over which style is right, you could rephrase the query and simply state that you wish to implement a certain formatting style and that you need help doing so. No need to justify your stylistic choices, is there?

Comment: @Mico I haven't claimed now that some styles are better than others. I only mention what I believe to be true, that there are more styles that put ``Jr.`` at the end than there are styles that don't. By "struggle to get it right", I'm referring to the designed ``BibTeX`` styles that fail to put ``Jr.`` at the end even though the style sheets they are designed for do so.

Comment: Thanks. Should we continue this discussion in chat?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard biblatex directives to format names use some auxiliary bibmacro:

```
name:first-last
name:last-first
name:last
```

For predefined name formats. Each of these take four arguments: the first is for the family name, the second is for the given name, the  third for the "von" part, and the fourth for the "junior" part.

Thus, one can use of the auxiliary format, for example

```
\DeclareNameFormat{author}{
  \usebibmacro{name:first-last}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}
}
```

For the parameters, `\DeclareNameFormat` splits a name in 8 parts:

```
#1: last name
#2: last name (as initials)
#3: first name
#4: first name (as initials)
#5: name prefix (von part)
#6: name prefix (as initials)
#7: name affix (junior part)
#8: name affix (as initials)
```

If the auxiliary bib macros do not produce the desired format, one has to provide a  new definition. For example, a simplified definition for the format in the OP can look like the following:

```
\DeclareNameFormat{author}{%
  \usebibmacro{name:delim}{#5#1}%
  \ifblank{#5}{#1}{#5 #1}\addcomma\addspace
  #3\isdot
  \ifblank{#7}{}{\addcomma\addspace #7}\isdot
}
```

`author` (or other names) are lists, thus `\DeclareNameFormat` loops over all the elements in the list (up to a limit if give, for example by `maxcitenames`) and for each name it executes the code it the body of the definition.

Here the first step is the predefined biblatex macro `name:delim`. This macro takes care of the punctuation between the names. For the first name it does nothing, for successive names it insert a comma an and a comma and and before the last one.

The second step is to see if the "von" part is empty (parameter `#5`): if it is it print the last name (parameter `#1`), otherwise it prints the von part and the last name (`#5 #1`).

The next step is to print first name (parameter `#3`) (here the definition assumes that there is a first name!), so the separator between the last and first name is printed with e first name.  The scope of `\isdot` is to ensure that a period in an initial is not consider as full stop,  and thus the following punctuation is not ignored.

The final step is to check if there is a junior part (parameter `#7`). If it is not black it is printed. The `\isdot` is to cover  the  same situation as before.

**EDIT**

To use the above  definition in a `last-first/first-last` schema, the above  definition can replace the standard `name:last-first` macro, namely:

```
\renewbibmacro{name:last-first}[4]{
  \usebibmacro{name:delim}{#3#1}%
  \ifblank{#3}{#1}{#3 #1}\addcomma\addspace
  #2\isdot
  \ifblank{#4}{}{\addcomma\addspace #4}\isdot
}
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to point out here that your output has this format: ``first name``-``middle initial``-``comma``-``last name``-``comma``-``affix``. I don't think that's a very common order in bibliographies.

Comment: I have changed it to produce the format you gave as an example

Comment: Would you mind adding some explanatory comments to your code snippets? If I understood well what the code is doing, I can modify it for future uses as well.

Comment: An issue arises when the entry has multiple authors. Please see the edit to my question.

Comment: What is format for the junior part when you have first-last name?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: As seen in [Commas in biblatex entries](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/261105/35864), this method has some disadvantages with monolithic names such as "Aristotle"  and "Plato".

Answer (score 1):

The approach I use when dealing with this situation is to enclose the last name and the "Jr." in curly brackets, like so:

```
AUTHOR = "Hugh G. {Gauch, Jr.}",
```

It's possible that sorting problems ensue, but until now I've had no issues.

Comment: But then a `\textcite` to this reference would be "see Gauch, Jr. [2]". Shouldn't rather be "see Gauch [2]"?