# Commas in biblatex entries

Tags: biblatex

First a warning. This is a highly specific and idiosyncratic problem I have that will only interest a few people who are very invested in `biblatex` and/or regular expressions.

From the answer to [Placement of Jr. and Sr. with biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209941/placement-of-jr-and-sr-with-biblatex), I'm using the following code:

```
\renewbibmacro{name:last-first}[4]{% put name affixes like 'Jr.' after the name
    \usebibmacro{name:delim}{#3#1}%
    \ifblank{#3}{#1}{#3 #1}\addcomma\addspace
    #2\isdot
    \ifblank{#4}{}{\addcomma\addspace #4}\isdot
}
```

And then from the answer to [Abbreviating a name in biblatex when first name is missing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/216199/abbreviating-a-name-in-biblatex-when-first-name-is-missing), I'm using this code:

```
\DeclareStyleSourcemap{
    \maps[datatype = bibtex]{
        \map{%% Make sure a field like [Adam John Smith] comes out as [Smith, Adam John]
            \step[fieldsource = author,
                match = \regexp{\A\[(.+)\s+([^\s]+)\]\Z},
                replace = {[$2, $1]}]
    }
        \map{%% Abbreviate an entry such as Adam J[ohn] Smith to Smith, Adam J.
            \step[fieldsource = author,
                match = \regexp{(\w+)\[(.+?)\]},
                replace ={$1.}]
    }
        \map{%% Abbreviate an entry such as [Adam John] Smith to Smith
            \step[fieldsource = author,
                notmatch = \regexp{\A\[(.+)\]\Z},
                final]
            \step[fieldsource = author,
                match = \regexp{(\A|\,\s)\[(.+?)\]},
                replace = {$1}]
    }
  }
}
```

These two code snippets don't work perfectly together, as the first code snippet causes the second code snippet to retain or include a comma after a bracketed first name as in `[John] Lennon` has been removed and replaced by `Lennon`. In the MWE below, instead of printing `Lennon (1974)`, it prints `Lennon, (1974)`. If you comment out the code that deals with name affixes like `Jr.`, then the desired output `Lennon (1974)` appears. So the question is, how should the code be modified so that it puts name affixes where I want them while at the same time it doesn't add the comma when I remove bracketed first names?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\renewbibmacro{name:last-first}[4]{% put name affixes like 'Jr.' after the name
    \usebibmacro{name:delim}{#3#1}%
    \ifblank{#3}{#1}{#3 #1}\addcomma\addspace
    #2\isdot
    \ifblank{#4}{}{\addcomma\addspace #4}\isdot
}
\DeclareStyleSourcemap{
    \maps[datatype = bibtex]{
        \map{%% Make sure a field like [Adam John Smith] comes out as [Smith, Adam John]
            \step[fieldsource = author,
                match = \regexp{\A\[(.+)\s+([^\s]+)\]\Z},
                replace = {[$2, $1]}]
    }
        \map{%% Abbreviate an entry such as Adam J[ohn] Smith to Smith, Adam J.
            \step[fieldsource = author,
                match = \regexp{(\w+)\[(.+?)\]},
                replace ={$1.}]
    }
        \map{%% Abbreviate an entry such as [Adam John] Smith to Smith
            \step[fieldsource = author,
                notmatch = \regexp{\A\[(.+)\]\Z},
                final]
            \step[fieldsource = author,
                match = \regexp{(\A|\,\s)\[(.+?)\]},
                replace = {$1}]
    }
  }
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{lennon1970,
    AUTHOR = "J[ohn] Lennon",
    TITLE = "My life with the Beatles",
    YEAR = "1970",
    SORTNAME = "John Lennon"}
@BOOK{lennon1971,
    AUTHOR = "[John Lennon]",
    TITLE = "Moving on",
    YEAR = "1971",
    SORTNAME = "John Lennon"}
@BOOK{lennon1972,
    AUTHOR = "[J. John Lennon]",
    TITLE = "Moving further on",
    YEAR = "1972",
    SORTNAME = "John Lennon"}
@BOOK{lennon1973,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "Still moving on",
    YEAR = "1973",
    SORTNAME = "John Lennon"}
@BOOK{lennon1974,
    AUTHOR = "[John] Lennon",
    TITLE = "I'm out of here",
    YEAR = "1974",
    SORTNAME = "John Lennon"}
@BOOK{lennon1975,
    AUTHOR = "Lennon, [John]",
    TITLE = "I'm out of here",
    YEAR = "1975",
    SORTNAME = "John Lennon"}
@BOOK{beatles1970,
    AUTHOR = "John W[inston] Lennon and J[ames] Paul McCartney",
    TITLE = "Let it be",
    YEAR = "1970"}
@BOOK{gauch2012,
    AUTHOR = "Gauch, Jr., Hugh G.",
    TITLE = "Scientific method in brief",
    YEAR = "2012",
    LOCATION = "Cambridge",
    PUBLISHER = "Cambridge University Press"}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When writing name macros, I think it always safer to take the standard definition (from `biblatex.def`) and apply one's modifications carefully. The standard definitions think of so many things I, for one, might not have considered.

In this case here, `name:last-first` did not fare well with names only consisting of one component such as "Aristotle", "Plato", or after our treatment "Lennon". In those cases it still added a comma in joyful anticipation of a first name that did not follow.

The macro below is just `name:last-first` from `biblatex.def` with a few lines shuffled around. The `\ifblank{#4}{}{...}` lines went to the end. Furthermore those were enhanced with a further `\revsdnamepunct`, to set off the Jr part. (Maybe it would have been more fitting to create a new `\bibnameaffixpunct` and use that instead)

```
\renewbibmacro*{name:last-first}[4]{%
  \ifuseprefix
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#3#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#3#1}%
     \ifblank{#3}{}{%
       \ifcapital
         {\mkbibnameprefix{\MakeCapital{#3}}\isdot}
         {\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}%
       \ifpunctmark{'}{}{\bibnamedelimc}}%
     \mkbibnamelast{#1}\isdot
     \ifblank{#2}{}{\revsdnamepunct\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamefirst{#2}\isdot}%
     \ifblank{#4}{}{\revsdnamepunct\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameaffix{#4}\isdot}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1}%
     \mkbibnamelast{#1}\isdot
     \ifblank{#2#3}{}{\revsdnamepunct}%
     \ifblank{#2}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamefirst{#2}\isdot}%
     \ifblank{#3}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}%
     \ifblank{#4}{}{\revsdnamepunct\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameaffix{#4}\isdot}}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp]{biblatex}


\renewbibmacro*{name:last-first}[4]{%
  \ifuseprefix
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#3#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#3#1}%
     \ifblank{#3}{}{%
       \ifcapital
         {\mkbibnameprefix{\MakeCapital{#3}}\isdot}
         {\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}%
       \ifpunctmark{'}{}{\bibnamedelimc}}%
     \mkbibnamelast{#1}\isdot
     \ifblank{#2}{}{\revsdnamepunct\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamefirst{#2}\isdot}%
     \ifblank{#4}{}{\revsdnamepunct\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameaffix{#4}\isdot}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1}%
     \mkbibnamelast{#1}\isdot
     \ifblank{#2#3}{}{\revsdnamepunct}%
     \ifblank{#2}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamefirst{#2}\isdot}%
     \ifblank{#3}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}%
     \ifblank{#4}{}{\revsdnamepunct\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameaffix{#4}\isdot}}}

\DeclareStyleSourcemap{
    \maps[datatype = bibtex]{
        \map{%% Make sure a field like [Adam John Smith] comes out as [Smith, Adam John]
            \step[fieldsource = author,
                match = \regexp{\A\[(.+)\s+([^\s]+)\]\Z},
                replace = {[$2, $1]}]
    }
        \map{%% Abbreviate an entry such as Adam J[ohn] Smith to Smith, Adam J.
            \step[fieldsource = author,
                match = \regexp{(\w+)\[(.+?)\]},
                replace ={$1.}]
    }
        \map{%% Abbreviate an entry such as [Adam John] Smith to Smith
            \step[fieldsource = author,
                notmatch = \regexp{\A\[(.+)\]\Z},
                final]
            \step[fieldsource = author,
                match = \regexp{(\A|\,\s)\[(.+?)\]},
                replace = {$1}]
    }
  }
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{lennon1970,
    AUTHOR = "J[ohn] Lennon",
    TITLE = "My life with the Beatles",
    YEAR = "1970",
    SORTNAME = "John Lennon"}
@BOOK{lennon1971,
    AUTHOR = "[John Lennon]",
    TITLE = "Moving on",
    YEAR = "1971",
    SORTNAME = "John Lennon"}
@BOOK{lennon1972,
    AUTHOR = "[J. John Lennon]",
    TITLE = "Moving further on",
    YEAR = "1972",
    SORTNAME = "John Lennon"}
@BOOK{lennon1973,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "Still moving on",
    YEAR = "1973",
    SORTNAME = "John Lennon"}
@BOOK{lennon1974,
    AUTHOR = "[John] Lennon",
    TITLE = "I'm out of here",
    YEAR = "1974",
    SORTNAME = "John Lennon"}
@BOOK{lennon1975,
    AUTHOR = "Lennon, [John]",
    TITLE = "I'm out of here",
    YEAR = "1975",
    SORTNAME = "John Lennon"}
@BOOK{beatles1970,
    AUTHOR = "John W[inston] Lennon and J[ames] Paul McCartney",
    TITLE = "Let it be",
    YEAR = "1970"}
@BOOK{gauch2012,
    AUTHOR = "Gauch, Jr., Hugh G.",
    TITLE = "Scientific method in brief",
    YEAR = "2012",
    LOCATION = "Cambridge",
    PUBLISHER = "Cambridge University Press"}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Gauch, Hugh G., Jr.]