# Placement of Jr. and Sr. with biblatex (v2)

Tags: biblatex, biber

This is another case in which a previous `biblatex` code no longer performs the desired function due to changes in `biber`/`biblatex`.

When running the code from [Commas in biblatex entries](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261105/commas-in-biblatex-entries), which itself is an update from [Placement of Jr. and Sr. with biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209941/placement-of-jr-and-sr-with-biblatex), the words `Jr.` and `Sr.` are no longer placed after the person's name in the reference list. I'm running `biblatex` verson 3.11 with `biber` version 2.11.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp]{biblatex}


\renewbibmacro*{name:last-first}[4]{%
  \ifuseprefix
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#3#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#3#1}%
     \ifblank{#3}{}{%
       \ifcapital
         {\mkbibnameprefix{\MakeCapital{#3}}\isdot}
         {\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}%
       \ifpunctmark{'}{}{\bibnamedelimc}}%
     \mkbibnamelast{#1}\isdot
     \ifblank{#2}{}{\revsdnamepunct\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamefirst{#2}\isdot}%
     \ifblank{#4}{}{\revsdnamepunct\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameaffix{#4}\isdot}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1}%
     \mkbibnamelast{#1}\isdot
     \ifblank{#2#3}{}{\revsdnamepunct}%
     \ifblank{#2}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamefirst{#2}\isdot}%
     \ifblank{#3}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}%
     \ifblank{#4}{}{\revsdnamepunct\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameaffix{#4}\isdot}}}

\DeclareStyleSourcemap{
    \maps[datatype = bibtex]{
        \map{%% Make sure a field like [Adam John Smith] comes out as [Smith, Adam John]
            \step[fieldsource = author,
                match = \regexp{\A\[(.+)\s+([^\s]+)\]\Z},
                replace = {[$2, $1]}]
    }
        \map{%% Abbreviate an entry such as Adam J[ohn] Smith to Smith, Adam J.
            \step[fieldsource = author,
                match = \regexp{(\w+)\[(.+?)\]},
                replace ={$1.}]
    }
        \map{%% Abbreviate an entry such as [Adam John] Smith to Smith
            \step[fieldsource = author,
                notmatch = \regexp{\A\[(.+)\]\Z},
                final]
            \step[fieldsource = author,
                match = \regexp{(\A|\,\s)\[(.+?)\]},
                replace = {$1}]
    }
  }
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{lennon1970,
    AUTHOR = "J[ohn] Lennon",
    TITLE = "My life with the Beatles",
    YEAR = "1970",
    SORTNAME = "John Lennon"}
@BOOK{lennon1971,
    AUTHOR = "[John Lennon]",
    TITLE = "Moving on",
    YEAR = "1971",
    SORTNAME = "John Lennon"}
@BOOK{lennon1972,
    AUTHOR = "[J. John Lennon]",
    TITLE = "Moving further on",
    YEAR = "1972",
    SORTNAME = "John Lennon"}
@BOOK{lennon1973,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "Still moving on",
    YEAR = "1973",
    SORTNAME = "John Lennon"}
@BOOK{lennon1974,
    AUTHOR = "[John] Lennon",
    TITLE = "I'm out of here",
    YEAR = "1974",
    SORTNAME = "John Lennon"}
@BOOK{lennon1975,
    AUTHOR = "Lennon, [John]",
    TITLE = "I'm out of here",
    YEAR = "1975",
    SORTNAME = "John Lennon"}
@BOOK{beatles1970,
    AUTHOR = "John W[inston] Lennon and J[ames] Paul McCartney",
    TITLE = "Let it be",
    YEAR = "1970"}
@BOOK{gauch2012,
    AUTHOR = "Gauch, Jr., Hugh G.",
    TITLE = "Scientific method in brief",
    YEAR = "2012",
    LOCATION = "Cambridge",
    PUBLISHER = "Cambridge University Press"}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problematic changes should be https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864 from 3.3 more than two years ago.

Comment: @moewe I don't think I'd be able to piece together from that what I need to do to put "Jr." back after the name.

Comment: OK, I'll have a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to changes in the name format for `biblatex` 3.3. See also [Biblatex 3.3 name formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864).

While details are different in the new name format, the general structure of macros like `name:family-given` (formerly `name:last-first`) has stayed the same. With some experience it is therefore possible to convert from the old to the new name format (as explained in Ulrike's answer to the linked question and the links there). So to make my life easier I just copied `name:family-given` from `biblatex.def` and compared it to your `name:last-first`. The only structural change to the original `name:family-given` is the position of the lines involving `#4`/`\mkbibnamesuffix`.

Note that I made the comma before "Jr."/"Sr." customisable with `\bibnamedelimsuffix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\newcommand*{\bibnamedelimsuffix}{\addcomma\bibnamedelimd}

\renewbibmacro*{name:family-given}[4]{%
  \ifuseprefix
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#3#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#3#1}%
     \ifdefvoid{#3}{}{%
       \ifcapital
         {\mkbibnameprefix{\MakeCapital{#3}}\isdot}
         {\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}%
       \ifprefchar{}{\bibnamedelimc}}%
     \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot
     \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{\revsdnamepunct\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamegiven{#2}\isdot}%
     \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimsuffix\mkbibnamesuffix{#4}\isdot}}
    {\usebibmacro{name:delim}{#1}%
     \usebibmacro{name:hook}{#1}%
     \mkbibnamefamily{#1}\isdot
     \ifboolexpe{%
       test {\ifdefvoid{#2}}
       and
       test {\ifdefvoid{#3}}}
       {}
       {\revsdnamepunct}%
     \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnamegiven{#2}\isdot}%
     \ifdefvoid{#3}{}{\bibnamedelimd\mkbibnameprefix{#3}\isdot}%
     \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{\bibnamedelimsuffix\mkbibnamesuffix{#4}\isdot}}}

\DeclareStyleSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype = bibtex]{
    \map{%% Make sure a field like [Adam John Smith] comes out as [Smith, Adam John]
      \step[fieldsource = author,
          match = \regexp{\A\[(.+)\s+([^\s]+)\]\Z},
          replace = {[$2, $1]}]
    }
    \map{%% Abbreviate an entry such as Adam J[ohn] Smith to Smith, Adam J.
      \step[fieldsource = author,
          match = \regexp{(\w+)\[(.+?)\]},
          replace ={$1.}]
    }
    \map{%% Abbreviate an entry such as [Adam John] Smith to Smith
      \step[fieldsource = author,
          notmatch = \regexp{\A\[(.+)\]\Z},
          final]
      \step[fieldsource = author,
          match = \regexp{(\A|\,\s)\[(.+?)\]},
          replace = {$1}]
    }
  }
}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{lennon1970,
    AUTHOR = "J[ohn] Lennon",
    TITLE = "My life with the Beatles",
    YEAR = "1970",
    SORTNAME = "John Lennon"}
@BOOK{lennon1971,
    AUTHOR = "[John Lennon]",
    TITLE = "Moving on",
    YEAR = "1971",
    SORTNAME = "John Lennon"}
@BOOK{lennon1972,
    AUTHOR = "[J. John Lennon]",
    TITLE = "Moving further on",
    YEAR = "1972",
    SORTNAME = "John Lennon"}
@BOOK{lennon1973,
    AUTHOR = "John Lennon",
    TITLE = "Still moving on",
    YEAR = "1973",
    SORTNAME = "John Lennon"}
@BOOK{lennon1974,
    AUTHOR = "[John] Lennon",
    TITLE = "I'm out of here",
    YEAR = "1974",
    SORTNAME = "John Lennon"}
@BOOK{lennon1975,
    AUTHOR = "Lennon, [John]",
    TITLE = "I'm out of here",
    YEAR = "1975",
    SORTNAME = "John Lennon"}
@BOOK{beatles1970,
    AUTHOR = "John W[inston] Lennon and J[ames] Paul McCartney",
    TITLE = "Let it be",
    YEAR = "1970"}
@BOOK{gauch2012,
    AUTHOR = "Gauch, Jr., Hugh G.",
    TITLE = "Scientific method in brief",
    YEAR = "2012",
    LOCATION = "Cambridge",
    PUBLISHER = "Cambridge University Press"}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Gauch, Hugh G., Jr. (2012). Scientific method in brief. Cambridge: Cambridge University Press.]